# Use mod_rewrite to rewrite get arguments with slashes

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website which has a few standalone webpages (like `signup.php`) and a main PHP file that displays the rest of the pages using a GET parameter.

I wish to rewrite HTTP requests to the server so that a request like:

`http://example.com/website/settings/` would display the page

`http://example.com/website/index.php?page=settings`, without affecting all the other pages.

I'm quite new to mod_rewrite and all of my attempts have resulted in either a 404 or 500 response code. What is the correct way to write the RewriteCond and RewriteRule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these rules in the htaccess file in the document root (where the `website` folder is in):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+website/(?:index\.php|)\?page=([^&]+)/(&|\ |$)
RewriteRule ^ /website/%1/ [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^website/(.+)/$ /website/index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Or you could instead put these rules in the `website` folder if that makes more sense:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /website/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+website/(?:index\.php|)\?page=([^&]+)/(&|\ |$)
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```